Ubuntu Cinnamon 24.04 Noble Numbat update question
Good day everyone! Just a quick question I Had Ubuntu Cinnamon 23.10.. I was doing a file update that finished all good --  then a message came up that 24.04 was avail for update so I clicked that option--Bingo the update to 24.04 went well works amazing! The problem I have when I boot my PC up everything loads but I see a message that states efi/ubuntu failed to open -- after seeing that message ubuntu loads almost instant! Is there a simple way to fix that issue? Thanks for any help!
